# Return the value from combobox in Tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Here's my ComboBox in Tkinter. When I want to choose something from this combobox nothing happens. I see all the options selected by the cursor from the database, but I'd say it is 'read-only'. For testing, I wrote one if statement to be sure that, but unfortunately messagebox doesn't appear. I think I need something more to operate this combobox, please help me.

```
var1 = StringVar()
lblChooseaModel = Label(bottomLeftTopR, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = 
"Choose a model", fg = "black", width = 13, bd = 14, anchor = 'w')

lblChooseaModel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

cboChooseaModel = ttk.Combobox(bottomLeftTopR, textvariable = var1, font = 
('arial', 20, 'bold'), width = 12)

models_query = cur.execute('SELECT name_of_model FROM models')
data_models = ['']
for row in models_query:
    data_models.append(row)

cboChooseaModel['value'] = data_models
cboChooseaModel.current(0)
cboChooseaModel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

if cboChooseaModel.get() == (data_models[1]):
    messagebox.showinfo("You chose Mazda 2")
```

When I print "data_models" I can see:

> [ ' ', ('Mazda 2'), ('Mazda 3'), ('Mazda 6'), ('Mazda CX 3'), ('Mazda CX 5') ]

Comment: can you add more context to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a trace to the Combobox's StringVar:

```
#tkinter setup
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
bottomLeftTopR = Tk()

def combo_choose(value):
    messagebox.showinfo("Choice", "You Chose " + value)

var1 = StringVar()
lblChooseaModel = Label(bottomLeftTopR, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'),text = "Choose a model",
                        fg = "black", width = 13, bd = 14, anchor = 'w')

lblChooseaModel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

cboChooseaModel = ttk.Combobox(bottomLeftTopR, textvariable = var1,
                               font = ('arial', 20, 'bold'), width = 12)

#models_query = cur.execute('SELECT name_of_model FROM models')
#data_models = ['']
#for row in models_query:
#    data_models.append(row)

# Replaced query with data
data_models = [ ' ', ('Mazda 2'), ('Mazda 3'), ('Mazda 6'), ('Mazda CX 3'), ('Mazda CX 5') ]

cboChooseaModel['value'] = data_models
cboChooseaModel.current(0)
cboChooseaModel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

var1.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: combo_choose(var1.get()))
```

You can do anything you want with the selected value, in the combo_choose function. In this code the list `chosen` is passed to the function and the value is appended to the list, then the list is printed.

```
#tkinter setup
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
bottomLeftTopR = Tk()

def combo_choose(chosen, value):
    chosen.append(value)
    print("You've chosen ", *chosen)
    print(chosen)

var1 = StringVar()
lblChooseaModel = Label(bottomLeftTopR, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'),text = "Choose a model",
                        fg = "black", width = 13, bd = 14, anchor = 'w')

lblChooseaModel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

cboChooseaModel = ttk.Combobox(bottomLeftTopR, textvariable = var1,
                               font = ('arial', 20, 'bold'), width = 12)

#models_query = cur.execute('SELECT name_of_model FROM models')
#data_models = ['']
#for row in models_query:
#    data_models.append(row)

# Replaced query with data
data_models = [ ' ', ('Mazda 2'), ('Mazda 3'), ('Mazda 6'), ('Mazda CX 3'), ('Mazda CX 5') ]

cboChooseaModel['value'] = data_models
cboChooseaModel.current(0)
cboChooseaModel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

chosen = []
var1.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: combo_choose(chosen, var1.get()))
```

Comment: I need to select records from the database. Each car's model has price in my database. My next step is to sum prices from every combobox for the final car's price, so replace query with data is wrong

Comment: I did that for me, since I have nothing to query, I was assuming the data provided was the result of the query.

Comment: Yes, it works! What if I want to save the selected value, not only show info?

Comment: I added an example of appending the value to a list.